# How can I make this code not use a list or a ton of conditional statements?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm making an AI, and I want it to be able to search things. I don't know how to do this efficiently though.

Edit again: I fixed it on my own.

Instead of taking the second word inside of a list which contains every word the output has and added it to a search query. I took the output and removed the first word from it (which is "find", or "search") and then it will add that to the search query. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If you remove your question once it has been answered, nobody else can get any benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's really all you want:

```
words = output.split(' ', 1)
if words[0] == 'search' and words[1] in Terms:
    print("win")
```

Comment: This would fail for the 'dank desmondo' case.

Comment: @JeffLorenzini Well, no, it doesn't, see my previous comment...

Comment: OK I fixed it for the multi-word case I had not noticed before.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer and showing it to me?

Comment: Um, as I said, I already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you could forget about that long if condition and try this:

```
Terms = ['music','gaming','Minecraft','dank desmondo']
output = "search music"
if output.split()[1] in Terms:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: This wont work for the multi word cases like 'dank desmondo' as `output` would be 'search dank desmondo' and `output.split()[1]` would give you 'dank' only, printing `False` when the correct answer was `True`.

Comment: right, I didn't notice the double worded string in there.